# Angular2 share data

Tags: angular

I have a component called UserListComponent, which own User array. I want this array to be accessible from another component.

UserListComponent :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { User } from './user';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'user-list',
    templateUrl: './app/user-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app/user-list.component.css']
})

export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
    users: User[];
    followedUsers: User[] = new Array();

    constructor(
        private userService: UserService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
}
```

My second component :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input }    from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule }   from '@angular/http';
import { User } from './user';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'carto',
    templateUrl: './app/carto.component.html'
})
export class CartoComponent {

    title: string;

    constructor(
        private userService: UserService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {


    }
}
```

I would like the "followedUsers" property to be accessible in "CartoComponent"
Those both components are instaciated in a parent one : "ExploitationComponent".

In the HTML file "exploitation.component.html" I instanciate my 2 components like this :

```
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <user-list></user-list>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="map-suivi">
            <carto></carto>
        </div>
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Why not use an `@Input()`? `<user-list [users]="users"></user-list>`. Have you read [the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)?

Comment: If I put my usersList in my parent component, I could pass it to both userlist and carto ? I mean, will the binding be still working ?

Comment: Oh, I see: it's currently in one child component and needs to be in a sibling too? Then yes, I'd suggest moving it to the parent.

Comment: Or make it an output from one child and an input to the other then bind it via the parent, but that seems a little wonky.

Comment: Okay, your first proposition worked well, thank you !